# Can't find bundle

Tags: java, javafx, resourcebundle

Всем доброго времени суток, вопрос в следующем:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("src\\locals",Locale.forLanguageTag("RU"), new UTF8Control());
```

Вывод `Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name src\locals, locale ru`

[image: Я пытаюсь вызвать bundle из controller]

Может кто-то направить на путь истинный?

Answer (score 0):

Путь к ресурсу надо указывать относительно корня classpath.
Вероятно та программа, вид окна которой на картинке, переложит ресурсы из директории src в classpath-директорию.
Значит нужно убрать `src\\` из `src\\locals`

Comment: я пытался, это не дало результатов

Comment: А где, в итоге, лежат файлы locals...properties?

Comment: src/locals.properties

Comment: А в момент исполнения программы?

Comment: в каком смысле?

Comment: JVM работает с classpath. Ищет классы и ресурсы в нём. Он найдёт ресурс, если ресурс есть в classpath. Директория src не находится в classpath.

Comment: я создал package "res" и закинул туда bundle, затем в настройках указал что res-Resource folder, но это не помогло. src у меня помечен как source folder, что же не так?

Comment: Вам надо изучить свою среду разработки. Что у неё на выходе при различных настройках. Может тогда удастся понять, что не так.